# Error: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. in RowDataBound Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, error-handling, rowdatabound

I want Bind data gridview and change data '0' to '-' . 
but error: **Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. Parameter name: index**

**Code asp**

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" 
  AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowPaging="true" 
  OnRowCreated="GridView1_RowCreated"  
  OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" >
   <Columns>
     <asp:BoundField DataField="amt" HeaderText="Total" 
          DataFormatString="{0:#,##0.00000}" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" />
   </Columns>               
 </asp:GridView>
```

**Code C#**

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
      {
          if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
          {                
             string sAmt = DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "amt").ToString();    

          if (sAmt == "0.00000")
          {
             e.Row.Cells[10].Text = "-"; <<< Line Error
          }
     }
 }
```

If fields AMT Show 0.

I want instead "0" to "-" .

Help me please. Thanks advance for time. ;)

Comment: Do you have 10 cells in the gridview? Please show the markup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the index of 10 in:

```
e.Row.Cells[10].Text = "-"; <<< Line Error
```

valid? I mean are there 11 items in the array, you might be trying to access something outside of the range of the array.

Comment: This should be a comment

Comment: Sorry yes I thought about this afterwards, it was more of a leading question than an answer, I was going to update this based on his reply but I see where you're coming from.

Comment: I try Array. it's 0.0000 have many records. i try new code. now it's working. Thx so much ;)

Answer (score 0):

Error message tells you that in GridView there is no cell with index of 10. Ensure that **Cells** array is large enought. 
May be should try

```
e.Row.Cells[e.Row.Cells.Length-1].Text = "-";
```

Comment: This will not take intended row it always get value in last cell of the row

Comment: Yeap. But this will always work (unless Cells are empty array) and not throw specified exception.
Anyway the problem in topic code - out of array bounds. How to solve - depends of hidden code.

Answer (score 0):

First of all check if there is 9th column (which is `e.Row.Cells[10]` starting from 0 )  exist in selected Row.

In case you want to display specific value in `GridView` cell use below methis with `TemplateField` of `Gridview`

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Gender">
         <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<% #GetLangID(Eval("langid2")) %>' />
         </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

This will be your Code Behind

```
public string GETLangID(object dataItem)
{
    string text = string.Empty;
    int? val = dataItem as int?;
    switch (val)
    {
        case 0:
            text = "-";
            break;
        case 1:
            text = "One";
            break;
        case 2:
            text = "two";
            break;

    }
    return text;
}
```